# Http request blocked on port 80

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, httpd, selinux, firewalld

I currently have Centos 7 installed on EC2 with the following:
Apache
Php
Mysql
Iptables
Firewalld

---

**Apache running**

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service ● httpd.service -
>   The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: active (running) since di 2016-01-26 01:18:52
>   UTC; 16min ago
>        Docs: man:httpd(8)
>              man:apachectl(8)   Process: 4387 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 4392 (httpd)
>   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic: 
>   0 B/sec"    CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
>              ├─4392 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
>              ├─4393 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
>              ├─4394 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
>              ├─4395 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
>              ├─4396 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
>              └─4397 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

**FIREWALLD Disabled:**

> ● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon    Loaded:
>   loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor
>   preset: enabled)    Active: inactive (dead)

**IPTABLES ENABLED**

> ● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: active (exited) since di 2016-01-26 01:14:23 UTC;
>   2min 27s ago   Process: 4317
>   ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 4317 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

**IPTABLES RULES**

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>   ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0            state
>   RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>
> ACCEPT     tcp  --
>   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
>
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp
>   dpt:22
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination

**Iptables sysconfig file:**

> *filter
>
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> :OUTPUT ACCEPT [214:43782]
>
> -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT COMMIT

**Selinux:**

> getenforce: Disabled

My virtualhosts are correct, pass the configtest and all.. So with these settings, I still receive nothing on my webserver. Nothing in my access logs or error logs.. What I am overseeing in my configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, did you open the port in your EC2 security group?

Comment: Michael Hampton, your a legend. I didnt knew I had to open the ports also in the EC2 security groups. After adding those, it instantly worked.